# Print Azure Data Studio Notebook

Tags: printing, azure-data-studio

Azure Data Studio.  I love it.  Wherever possible I am working in ADS instead of SSMS, gradually moving stand-alone SQL scripts to notebooks.  Notebooks are so useful.  Rich-text commenting of code using markdown, making a great way of documenting scripts.

But how to print it?

I loaded the notebook into notepad.  It is a JSON file.  So I am thinking maybe I can do some kind of XSLT transform.  Seems that JSLT may be way to go.  But there has to be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the notebook (its a .ipynb file) just like any other Jupyter notebook in Jupyter lab and print from there. Works for me.

Comment: When I load a notebook into Visual Studio Code, it doesn't show graphs.  Does Jupyter Lab display graphs in a ADS notebook?